# Remote image downloading with progress?

Tags: android, listview, imageview, progress

I want to add functionality to download image into imageview from internet and while ImageView is loading it should show ProgressBar in ListView

I have seen example of droid fu which is very difficult and hard to understand any one guide me if any one has implemented functionality like this and how to achieve this any guidance with example would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you have so far? Show us that you have made your own effort.

Comment: follow this tutorial : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to call:

```
ImageLoader.initialize(context);
```

Now, to download an Image you call:

```
ImageLoader.start(imageUrl, new CustomImageLoaderHandler(imageUrl, imageView));
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressBar.bringToFront();
```

This will triger the image download and show the progress bar (your progress bar should be in a frame layout along with the imageView).

To catch the event of done downloading the image and release the progressbar you should extend the class ImageLoaderHandler and override handleImageLoaded as follow (you have to call super in order to let droidFu handle the cach).

```
private class TFImageLoaderHandler extends ImageLoaderHandler{

    public TFImageLoaderHandler(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
        super(imageView, imageUrl);         
    }       

    @Override
    protected boolean handleImageLoaded(Bitmap arg0, Message arg1) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return super.handleImageLoaded(arg0, arg1);
    }
}
```